# Fixed Shopping Cart, moves on scroll but does not stick to the top of page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two small problems with my sticky shopping cart:

1. It will not stick to the top of the page.
2. It will not float right.

I have a fixed shopping cart that works perfectly, my problem is the shopping cart is placed a while down the page on page load, lets say 200px for this example, the moment i scroll down the page, the shopping cart scrolls with me but has 200px spacing above it, instead of sticking to the top of the page.

The cart will not float right, no matter what i try.

Any suggestions on how i would resolve this:

```js
   $(window).on("scroll", function() {
            if($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
                $("#cart").css("top","right",$(window).scrollTop());
              
            }
        });
```

```css
#cart{
    width: 25%;
    float:right;
    margin: 20px;
    margin-top:10%;;
    float:right;
     
    position: fixed;
}
```

```html
       <div id="cart">
            <p id='order'>My Order</p>
            <p id='estimated'>Average Delivery <br>
                <b id='avg'><?php echo $avg_del ?></b><br> minutes</p> 
            <div id="prods_here">
                <!-- PLACE PRODUCTS HERE-->
<?php cart(); ?>  
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `position: fixed;` so you have to specify your position in relation to the browser window. So, if you want to float it right, you'd have to do something like:

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
```

As far as the top margin, you are writing, `margin-top: 10%;` which is creating the margin, make it `0` if you don't want it there

Comment: My problem is. on page load, i need my shopping cart to be postponed 10% from the top, then on scroll fixed to the top

Comment: Ah ok, I see. Well it seems you are on the right path. I would use `.css` method and do something like `$('#cart').css('margin-top', '0')` in conjunction with your scroll method logic you have there.

Comment: Okay great! i am sure that only make it stick to the top, but ill play around with it and hopefully get it to work

Comment: Ya, that's why I say in conjunction with your scroll logic. I'm willing to help more if you post a fuller example of your code or a codepen - it's just kinda hard to replicate that scroll when there is so little html to work with.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much. I understandably fully. After a little playing around i got it to work, amazing. One more question on scrolling back up, how would i go about getting the shopping cart to go back to the original position instead of scrolling back up all the way to the top. margin bottom?

Comment: Cool! You'd have to add more logic, something like `if($(window).scrollTop() == 0)` `{$('#cart').css('margin-top', '10%')}`

Answer (score 2):

Edit: You need to only assign `position: fixed` after a you pass the desired scrolltop, it should not be position fixed before.

Also, you can't `float` a `fixed` element. Instead, use `right: 0; top: 0; position: fixed;` when you want to stick it to the top right. If you need the children to float you can apply float to all the children.

Comment: Great! Thank you! Issue 1 sorted.